# ubuntu 12.10 failed to create a file system error

Tags: partitioning, 12.10

I would like to install ubuntu 12.10 on my system but i am getting an error " The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sda) failed "'
please help !!
during installation i select "Erase and install ubuntu option".
my S.M.A.R.T. in the bios in Enabled, the other options are Disabled and Auto.

please help my pc is dead for a week.

Answer (score 0):

try to manage hardrive using ubuntu boot live cd .Search for gparted in dash ,you can create and manage partitions easy with this instructions here is video and link to manual

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBCHsgry2RQ
  http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/